# AWS Tomcat on Elastic Beanstalk servlet Filter

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I'm trying to launch my web application for the first time on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (platform: Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.0.0).

It succeeds in creating the application in beanstalk but when it tries to launch my application (uploaded with a war) it throws an error:

```
04-Jun-2018 20:44:02.060 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter SecurePathFilter
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4708)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1126)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1868)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The SecurePathFilter is a javax.servlet.Filter class so I'm thinking it might be that jsp and servlet api jars are missing on the tomcat (or perhaps some other version of what I used locally) but how can I check this? And how could I add/change them?

Edit:
As requested, the relevant pieces of my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SecurePathFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>be.qsds.sade.filters.SecurePathFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurePathFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

and my SecurePathFilter class is roughly:

```
public class SecurePathFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ...

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your web.xml and SecurePathFilter class

Comment: @jontro I've appended the info to my question

Comment: Implement all methods of Filter, there must be a mismatch between the java versions or servlet apis used.

Answer (score 0):

@jontro led me in the right direction of the solution to my problem. I was building my application locally with the latest version of javax.servlet-api (4.0.1), where the Tomcat8.5 auto deployed on AWS uses an older version (3.1.0).

I changed the version in my pom, added some missing methods, rebuilt and uploaded my war and eureka!

Thanks for the guidance!